# NSSplitView with toolbars

Tags: nssplitview

I'm trying to make an application that looks like the Messages app from Apple.

The `NSSplitView` has toolbars on both subviews of the `NSSplitView`. They blend in with the top toolbar. It's similar to the `NSToolBar` but that doesn't work in `NSSplitView`'s. Is there any way to make this work?

I tried the `CNSplitView` but it doesn't provide the proper effect. Is there another way of doing this that I'm missing?

The interface i'm going for is here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using NSToolbar, you can add your own views to the top of subviews in the NSSplitView to achieve this after hiding the existing titlebar.

NSWindow's `titleVisibility` can be used to hide the built-in titlebar, and by setting the window's `styleMask` to include `NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask` you can cause the split view to take up the full height of the window.

To get the blur effect like toolbars/Messages you can use NSVisualEffectView in the top views. Setting the material `NSVisualEffectMaterialTitlebar` will give the same look as standard titlebars.

And finally, you can put `NSStackView`s inside the visual effect views, and then place the titlebar controls in there.

(And depending on the content that is below your fake toolbars, you might want to look into NSScrollView's `contentInsets` property to allow the scroll view to show all of the content, but still be able to scroll under your toolbar).